# In R - how do I replace all letters in a string with other letters?

Tags: r, anonymize

I need to anonymize names but in a very specific way so that the format of the entire string is still the same (spaces, hyphens, periods are preserved) but all the letters are scrambled.  I want to consistently replace say all A's with C's, all D's with Z's, and so on.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 6):

We can use `chartr`

```
chartr('AD', 'CZ', str1)
#[1] "CZ,ZC. C"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('AD,DA. C')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `gsub`?

```
    string <- "ABCDEFG"
    text <- gsub('A', 'C', string )
    string <- gsub('D', 'Z', string )

    string 
    [1] "CBCZEFG"
```